# Problem with archive news module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

I have a site with many latest news articles from the last 18 months.
Using the default archived news module we can generate a list of months eg Janury 2016 etc

However, we find that articles in January are appearing in both the list for January 2015 and January 2016

The notes on the joomla site say the archive only filters by month. How do I get it to filter by year as well?

You can see this if you want at http://www.treeferns.com/latest-news

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I can see that you are running Joomla v3.4.1. There is a critical security vulnerability with all versions of Joomla lower that 3.4.7 https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5643-joomla-3-4-7.html You should update your site immediately to v3.4.8, which is latest J! version at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google tells me that:
- On 2015-04-11 was opened Joomla Tracker Issue #6745 "**[Issues with the article module archive #6745](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/6745)**" with almost same simptoms as yours.
- On 2015-04-29 Issue was closed with explanation that it is caused by routing problem, with no code attached, but recommendation to open new tracker for routing.

I am personally just an integrator and not a developer, so I can not easily track these events and changes on GitHub, but I am under impression that this bug is still not fixed in newest Joomla yet. Maybe someone with bigger developer's experience here on JSE can shed some light on this issue, or can 'read' better than me this event-flow on GitHub.

On a side note, I have found extension **[Monthly Archive](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/monthly-archive)** which might help you solve these problems, but it is commercial.

Comment: You're quite welcome.